# Evaluating limits in dimensions greater than $1$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits

I am trying to calculate the following limit:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} {x\over x + ix}$$

The top moves towards $0$ along the $x$-axis and the bottom moves towards zero along the diagonal (in the complex plane).

If this was all on the $x$-axis I could apply de l'Hopital's rule. But now that it's in two dimensions I don't know what I could do.

> How to evaluate limit expressions in two and more dimensions?

Comment: Here all we need to do is cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x+ix}$$
>   $$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x(1+i)}$$
>   $$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1+i}$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{1+i}$$

Comment: I really do not see the point of writing out the answer completely when Andre Nicolas has already commented on how to do it